# Can not capture mouseup event in IE7

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-maps

I was working on a project on which I need to drag a google map marker to some dom element(e.g. a img in my code) and when I release my mouse I need to trigger a function.

Here is how I do it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
        html { height: 100% }body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }#map-canvas
        { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
    </script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var map;
        var tempMarker;
        function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(35.861660, 104.1953970),
                zoom: 4,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
            addMarkers();
        }
        function addMarkers() {
            var marker0 = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(32.04, 118.78),
                map: map,
                draggable: true,
                raiseOnDrag: false
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker0, 'dragstart',
            function(event) {
                tempMarker = this.getPosition();
                var addToPlan = "<div style='width: 130px; height: 38px;position: absolute;right: 50px;bottom: 50px;' id='addToPlan' ><img id='add_img' src='http://www.w3schools.com/html/img_w3slogo.gif' /></div>";
                $(document.body).append(addToPlan);
                $('#add_img').mouseup(function() {
                    alert('mouseup');
                });
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker0, 'dragend',
            function(event) {
                this.setPosition(tempMarker);
                // $('#addToPlan').remove();
            });
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="map-canvas" />
</body>

</html>
```

Unfortunately, It doesn't work on IE7. If you drag a marker to the picture, it won't trigger the function, however, if you click on the picture directly, the mouseup events can be captured!

Note: I didn't remove the img element when the drag is end so you can click the img directly, however, it can not capture the mouseup event if you drag the marker for twice.

Comment: Just a quick comment. First, you are missing `;` at the end of your `alert('mouseup')`. Second, the `,` at the end of `raiseOnDrag: false,` is unnecessary which according to `JSHint` will break older version of IE.

Comment: Thanks for your remind.I have corrected the mistakes, however, nothing changed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Through `mouseup` can not be fired, `mousemove` acts like `mouseup`.**